# image segmentation techniques

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr, face-detection, image-segmentation

I am working on a computer vision application and I am stuck at a conceptual roadblock. I need to recognize a set of logos in a video, and so far I have been using feature matching methods like SIFT (and ASIFT by Yu and Morel), SURF, FERNS -- basically everything in the "Common Interfaces of Generic Descriptor Matchers" section of the OpenCV documentation.  But recently I have been researching methods used in OCR/Random Trees classifier (I was playing with this dataaset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Letter+Recognition) and thinking that this might be a better way to go about finding the logos.  The problem is that I can't find a reliable way to automatically segment an arbitrary image.

My questions:

1. Should I bother looking into methods other than descriptor/keypoint, or is this the
   best way to recognize a typical logo (stylized, few colors, sharp edges)?
2. How can I segment an arbitary image (or a video frame, in my case) so that I can properly
   match against a sample database?
3. It would seem that HaarCascades work in a similar way (databases of samples), but I
   can't figure out how the processes are related. Is there segmentation going on there?

Sorry of these questions are too broad.  I'm trying to wrap my head around this stuff with little help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like segmentation is not what you want. I think it has to do more with object detection and recognition. You want to detect the presence of a certain set of logos, in a certain set of images. This doesn't seem related to segmentation which is about labeling surfaces or areas of a common color, texture, shape, etc., although examining segmentation based methods may be useful.

I would definitely encourage you to look at problem and examine all possible methods that can be applied, not only the fashionable ones (such as SIFT, GLOH, SURF, etc). I would recommend you look at older, simpler methods like simple template matching, chamfering, etc.

Haar cascades became popular after a 2000 paper by Viola and Jones used for face detection (similar to what you see in modern point and click cameras). It does sound a bit similar to the problem you are interested in. You should perhaps also examine this part of the problem, but try not to focus too much on the learning part.